# WCF and Service Registry

Tags: wcf, soa, software-as-a-service

I am about to build some WCF Services. Those services need to communicate to each others too, in some scenarios.

I've done some "Google-ing" about Service Registry but can't figure out how to implement service registry with WCF; is there any other alternate?

Is there any Microsoft technology available for Service Registry?

I'm new to SOA and I will really appreciate any help or guidance (what and where should I exactly look for registry services).

Answer (score 2):

Please describe what you think a Service Registry is. If it is the same as a [UDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration) registry, I recommend you NOT do this, certainly not at first, possibly not ever. The reasons to NOT use include (a) complexity, (b) low value, and (c) lack of industry support.

If you are trying to figure out how your services will be found and accessed, focus on WSDL and good old documentation. You may also want to read about some [SOA principles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx) to guide your design, and also think about whether you want REST services or SOAP services.

(Sigh... I do not have sufficient permissions on this site to post more than two links, so I deleted the REST and SOAP links. You can find descriptions on Wikipedia.)

REST services are more common over the public internet, whereas SOAP services are more common within a company. There are more tools for SOAP. REST is lighter weight, but a little more programming.

Good luck! -Bill

Comment: Implementing REST on WCF is coming along: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529